# How to prevent race conditions when using S3 as a database with concurrent writes?

Tags: java, database, amazon-s3, concurrency

My application has been using S3 as a database through a library I developed to implement a "database layer" for S3 operations. Although it's not that fast, it's sufficient for my use case.

The problem is race conditions:

- **Your application checks:** You use `HeadObject` to see if an object
  exists.
- **No object found:** Your logic decides to proceed with a
  PutObject request.
- **Meanwhile (in another process):** Another process or
  application instance creates an object with the same key in the S3
  bucket.
- **Your put request arrives:** Your application now overwrites the
  object that was just created by the other process.

Here is the code that my application uses for the PUT method:

```
public boolean put(String key, InputStream value, boolean putIfAbsent) {
        validateInputs(key, value);

        if(s3Client == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("S3 client is not initialized");
        }

        if(bucketName == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("bucketName cannot be null");
        }

        if (putIfAbsent && isExists(key)) {
            return false;
        }

        ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
        metadata.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
        metadata.setContentLength(calculateInputStreamLength(value));
        PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, key, value, metadata);
        request.setMetadata(metadata);
        request.withTagging(new ObjectTagging(new LinkedList<Tag>()));
        PutObjectResult result = s3Client.putObject(request);

        return result != null;
}
```

The web application that uses this library runs on multiple servers and interfaces with the same S3 bucket. Placing the object *check-before-write* in the application logic may result in race conditions.

I'm facing a challenge with conditional PUT to S3, and I'm hoping someone could suggest a viable workaround or an alternative solution. Any help or guidance on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is the key generated?  Perhaps include a GUID, which should be unique across JVMs.

Comment: S3 has no concept of a lock, or a primitive like an interlocked exchange that can be used to create a lock.  This means you'll either need external knowledge like being able to name keys based off the uploader's ID to prevent collisions, or some service like a proper database that can provide a lock for you.

Comment: @AndrewS the key is generally any string since it is a key-value store. So it can be like `username:andrew_s:user_id` then the object stored is a serialized object value (a String, a primitive, or an object) in this case, it would be the serialized value `1234567890` for example. So adding a GUID I think doesn't solve the check-before-write in the application logic problem.

Comment: If the key is unique per request, then there wouldn't be anything to check before writing.  Maybe I'm not understanding...

Comment: Saving unique keys is not the problem, but race conditions that occur when saving or updating the same keys.

Comment: @AndrewS you may check the complete code https://github.com/divroll/dyno
it's open source anyway, but after a bit of research, I am thinking of implementing atomix/copycat for a distributed lock for keys or something similar. The problem though, is that it would not work on platforms like Heroku.